# Android listview scrolls down automatically on db insertion

Tags: android, listview, scroll, refresh

I have a table connected with a listview using adapter. Whenever an item in the table gets inserted, the listview item currently in focus goes down by one cell. I want the item I am focusing on to be stayed like that for better user experience. How would I implement this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Please try "your_list_view.setSelection(x)", where x should be "your_list_view.getCount() - 1".
Call setSelection(x) whenever you add a new item from the table.

PS: you might need to call your_list_view.invalidate() after inserting a new item from your table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

where count_size=user_listArrayList.size();
  _list.setSelection(count_size);

Comment: @Jyothish ..If these code is workable for you than please mark the answer right..  :)